# Installing outlook 2019 failed

Tags: microsoft-outlook, installation

I reinstalled Office 2019 to add Outlook. I only use Excel, Word, and PowerPoint so I used the office deployment tool to customize the install. After reinstalling Outlook was not installed despite the fact that it was not excluded.

This is th XML file I used:

```xml
<Configuration ID="acad4124-7131-4f40-b906-1d6aab5687f1">
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="PerpetualVL2019">
    <Product ID="ProPlus2019Volume" PIDKEY="REDACTED">
      <Language ID="he-il" />
      <Language ID="en-us" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Access" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Lync" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="OneDrive" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="OneNote" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Publisher" />
    </Product>
    <Product ID="ProofingTools">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="TRUE" />
  <Property Name="DeviceBasedLicensing" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="SCLCacheOverride" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1" />
  <Updates Enabled="TRUE" />
  <RemoveMSI />
</Configuration>
```

My license is active and shows eligable for Outlook

Comment: Try uninstalling everything Office 2019, restart, and then install the entire package. Outlook will install this way.

Comment: thanks @John. I uninstalled evreything manually and it worked. I didn't have to restart the computer. Please add an answer so other poeple can find it and give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I reinstalled Office 2019 to add Outlook. .....  After reinstalling
> Outlook was not installed

What I do in this case and what I suggest here is to uninstall everything related to Office 2019.

Then restart the computer.

Now install the full package and Outlook will install this way.

Comment: I didn't have to restart but maybe others will need to

Comment: Restarts vary in need - I do them as often it is helpful. Thanks.